# iPhone Device UUID - PhoneGap

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova

I'm trying to get the UUID on iPhone 4.x simulator, however `device.uuid` stops my app from running. I've also tried `DeviceInfo.uuid` but this returns undefined despite being able to see the uuid in the DeviceInfo object in the debugger console.

Any ideas what I should be using?

I'm using PhoneGap 1.0.0

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I experienced the same problem, not just with `device.uui`, but with other events. In my case the problem was that XCode 4 put a reference in the html file to `phonegap.js` instead of `phonegap.{ver}.js`.

Answer (score 2):

Its important to note the difference between a UDID and a UUID.

UDID "unique device id" is hardware specific. It never changes for a particular device. For this reason, it has become a privacy concern and Apple is blocking apps that try to use this. As a result, Apple has generated an opt-out-able "device id" hash, particularly for advertisement usage. This new ID hash is called IFA and is available in iOS 6.0+.

UUID "universally unique id" is not hardware specific. It is a hash used to identify a device; but not particularly an absolute value. PhoneGap generates a UUID based on device properties; this is what you get when you do device.uuid. If you delete the app and reinstall, you will get a new id hash. *UUID is not being blocked by Apple*.

Comment: Do you have a source?

Answer (score 1):

It is a vague idea but: I think you actually cannot get an UUID from the simulator?

It could be that the simulator does not offer the same underlying architecture as a real device does.

And because a UUID is **UNIQUE** abd considering the fact that there are thousands of people using the simulator with Xcode I highly doubt apple would ship a unique UUID with every simulator, too.

Have you tried using a actual device?

HTH

Comment: Thanks, I thought this might the case. However the debugger console shows a UUID being generated. I've not got access to a device today to test it on.